# How to handle a violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an `UPDATE` statement on a table which throws an error

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint ...

I want SQL Server not to stop the update, but rather just ignore that error.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't disable a `UNIQUE` `CONSTRAINT`. You would need to `DROP` it.

Comment: Either Drop the Unique Constraint, or use an UPDATE or DELETE to remove or alter the unique data prior to your UPDATE to ensure you don't conflict with the constraint.

Comment: Reviewers, despite OP's lack of understanding of the issue at hand here, this is not an opinion-based question.

Comment: Ask yourself why would you like to "ignore" a constraint. A constraint keeps the data quality at a high level. If you drop the constraint you are essentially allowing any data to be saved in the database regardless of its quality.

Comment: You can't, but there are steps you can take to avoid the error.  It depends on the form of your update.  If it is a multi-row update you could add a WHERE condition that prevents the statement from attempting the bad update.